# tr:nth-child not working in mvc view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I read a lot of questions about my problem, but none were really effective for my case. I have this style in the upper part of my view (I know, I'll later transfer it to the bootstrap). My goal is to make my table have alternative row shading. I don't particularly care about the colors for now, I just want the functionality.

I run the site on Mozilla and Chrome. I have refreshed the cache.

```
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid gray;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-right: none;
        background: white;
        color: #333333; /*#333333*/
    }

    table {
        border-left: none;
    }

    th {
        text-align: center;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd)       { background:#eee; }
    tr:nth-child(even)      { background:#fff; }
</style>
```

I have a table with the following format:

```
<div class="tableIndex">
        <table id="tableBe">
            <tr>
               <th></th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="25" , align="left" style="border-left:none !important">
                        <b>No issues match search criteria</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

Everything works, except for the nth-child styling. Please assist. Sorry for the code wall, I just need to point out that I have an if construction there.

When I try to inspect element, I get no reference to the tr:nth-child commands, although I get the other effects in the `<style>`. Please assist. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove background: white; 
https://jsfiddle.net/3940hwke/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you have `background: white;` on `td`

move `background: white;` from `table,th,td {` and put it under `table {`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have set `td`'s background earlier. So set `td`'s background instead of `tr`. Following should work

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td  { background:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even) td { background:#fff; }
```

**Full Code**

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-right: none;
    background: white;
    color: #333333; /*#333333*/
}

table {
    border-left: none;
}

th {
     text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
     background: #eee;
 }

tr:nth-child(even) td {
     background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>111111111</td><td>2222222222</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111111111</td><td>2222222222</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111111111</td><td>2222222222</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111111111</td><td>2222222222</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is applying color to your `tr` based on your condition. But it got overwrite with the styles you have applied for th and td background color. So change your style like below.

```
    tr:nth-child(odd) td{ background:#eee; }
    tr:nth-child(even) td { background:#fff; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/r84228me/1/)